# Apollo writeFragment returns undefined but readFragment works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to update cache once an event is done. I cache event data from my selectedEvent fragment, and then I tried to write the changes to cache.

**readFragment works:**

```
const event = client.readFragment({
    id: `Event:5cc16ebcc922430697c49dea`,
    fragment: gql`
fragment selectedEvent on Event {
  _id
  title
  start
  end
  done
}
`;
});
console.log(event)
```

**writeFragment does not work and returns undefined:**

```
const updated = store.writeFragment({
    id: `Event:5cc16ebcc922430697c49dea`,
    fragment: gql`
        fragment finish on Event {
            done
        }
    `,
    data: {
        done: true,
        __typename: "Event"
    },
});
setEvent(updated)
console.log(updated)
```

[image]

Comment: `writeFragment` [always returns undefined](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-client/src/ApolloClient.ts#L443), so that alone doesn't mean that it's not working. Can you clarify why you think the write is failing? Are you seeing any errors? Are you not seeing the change in the store using developer tools? If your UI is not updating, you should include the relevant component code.

Comment: @DanielRearden I was actually passing the data from the readFragment to state, and this was why it was not updating on writeFragment. Thanks for letting me know that it always returns undefined. Good to know :)